# "In the" vs "At the"

Tags: word-choice

I am not sure which one is correct:

> In the beginning of the book

or

> At the beginning of the book

As in the sentence:

> In the beginning of the book Marco describes his early life.

Comment: I think this is one for English.SE.

Comment: Ops sorry... what is the difference between the two then?

Comment: No worries. English.SE is for questions about the English language, grammar, vocabulary... And we're for questions on the craft, process, and business of writing. See the first question in our FAQ: http://writers.stackexchange.com/faq .

Comment: Closed, but not moved?  May I publically wonder why?

Comment: I was thinking the same. And downvoted too :-(

Answer (score 4):

"In the" sounds like it's going on for a while — a chapter or two.

"At the" sounds like a point on a line: he describes everything in one or two paragraphs and then moves on.

Both are grammatically correct, but I think they have slightly different shades of meaning.

Comment: I'd agree. "In the beginning of the book" could be anywhere in the first couple of chapters. "At the beginning of the book" sounds like within the first chapter, perhaps even the first few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine.  But they have slightly different... connotations.

"In the beginning" makes most people in the western world think/associate that ancient book called the (Christian) Bible.  Which starts out with "In the beginning" ;-)

So, it gets a more epic feel right off the bat than if I started with "At the beginning".  "At the beginning" is more modern-sounding (to my ears, anyway).

And "At the beginning" makes me automatically think of a state more than a process ("In" is more neutral that way).  So, "At the beginning of our tale, Marco is standing in his workshop" is something I would expect.

Hmm, come to think of it some more, this sounds like a synopsis more than an actual book.  Or maybe it's not a question about writing fiction but about writing non-fiction?  Or writing non-fiction about fiction? ;-)  If so, then my answer is probably way off.

Comment: Wish you could tag answers...

Answer (score 0):

Either is fine to my ear/eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I think of things happening in sections of books, not at (which implies a location) sections of books.

I also tried changing it around:

> Marco describes his early life in the
> beginning of the book.
>
> Marco describes his early life at the
> beginning of the book.

"In" is my choice.